# "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Tags: php, database, laravel, upload, cpanel

I have used Laravel 5.7. I get this error only in production, locally my app runs smoothly. I've tried changing:

> 'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1')

**To**

> 'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost') in config/database.php

Comment: Have you change the `.env` file for database configuration?

Comment: Are you sure that your database password for `'homestead'@'localhost'` on the production environment is correct?

Comment: yes i'm sure my database password is correct on production environment

Comment: Doesn't the IP for localhost always resolve to 127.0.0.1? So they are the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

Just set up correct Database credentials:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql 
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 
DB_PORT=3306 
DB_DATABASE=            // Your Database Name
DB_USERNAME=           // Yout Database Username
DB_PASSWORD=          // Your Database Password
```

After completion of `.env` edit please enter this command in your terminal for clear cache: `php artisan config:cache`